# How to apply label to a reply message in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I like to keep my reply messages with the original message, rather than looking for them in the 'sent' folder. But I don't see any way to apply a label when drafting a reply and when I hit send Gmail doesn't seem to apply the label from the original message either.  Is there anything I can do to either have the reply automatically labeled the same way as the orginal or to add a label to the reply?

Comment: are you using conversation view?

Comment: No, I'm not using that view, just the default view